# android 2.3.4 -Date not appearing in status bar

Tags: android, date, statusbar

I am making a theme for a rom and wanted to add date just below the quick panel settings.

I edited the status_bar_expanded.xml with the below code.

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.DateView android:textStyle="bold" 
android:textSize="9.0sp" android:id="@id/date" android:textColor="#ffffffff" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="1.0dip" 
android:paddingBottom="1.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
```

---

but still date is not displayed. Screenshot attached

[image]

Also the color of date doesn't change.

Comment: try setting `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: basically I shifted the place of showing the date so I guess we have to call that dateview class at new place.
but i dont know how to